# Advanced Passive Cooling Solution Needed (for Xeon Phi)

Tags: pc, cooling, processor

**Premise**

I have seen interesting external vacuum/clamp on coolers that are mounted on laptops to cooldown the hot air around the fan as seen [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01NACVLWM). As laptops don't have liquid cooling, this seems to be one of the most effective cooling solutions available.

With this in mind, I want to see if I can apply an equally effective approach to a coprocessor that doesn't have liquid cooling capabilites (such as the Xeon Phi). I have seen people mount normal external fans on the back of the desktop PC case to help the passively cooled Xeon Phi, but I am convinced there must be a better mousetrap, so to speak.

**Why can't I just use normal fans?**

The Xeon Phis are ungodly expensive, and I don't want some rinky-dink fan have to be responsible for this huge investment. I also have performance in mind, if I can bring temperatures down, the coprocessor will be able to work better. And lastly, by reducing the strain, I can hopefully improve the lifespan of the Xeon Phi's in a more meaningful degree than your average fan can hope to match.

**What am I looking for?**

Maybe something similar to the laptop product I alluded to above (but for desktops)?

Specifically, a hardware solution that:

- Can provide better passive cooling than normal desktop fans
- Can be mounted to the back of a PC case (or modified to do so)
- Can be stacked vertically, as I may get 2 Xeon Phis for the desktop PC
- Can be powered by the existing power supply of the desktop PC. PSU is a 700W EVGA as seen [here](http://www.evga.com/products/product.aspx?pn=100-B1-0700-K1). I'm willing to change PSU's if necessary.
- Can be bought in the color: black (I guess other colors wouldn't be a deal killer)
- I might as well go all out, budget: $300

Comment: Nice. The only other thing I can think of is this: what is the existing PSU?

Comment: The usual solution here is ducted fans, but those are generally custom-built for a specific setup.

Comment: Have you thought about some ungodly peltier and a huge radiator? Basically the larger the radiator the more heat is transferred to the surroundings.

Comment: @Avamander is there an existing setup so I can see how hardcore other people have gone with that idea?

Comment: @ArashHowaida I think you'd be better off googling something like "extreme passive cooling" or "(enter Xeon Phi wattage here) watt passive cooling".